# What's the time complexity of for (int i = 2; i < n; i = i*i)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, runtime

What would be the time complexity of the following loop?

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i = i * i) {
    ++a;
}
```

While practicing runtime complexities, I came across this code and can't find the answer. I thought this would be `sqrt(n)`, though it doesn't seem correct, since the loop has the sequence of `2, 4, 16, 256, ...`.

Comment: fwiw, you have it all right there in place to measure the complexity of the loop. Choose different values for `n` and see what is the relation between `n` and the final value of `a`

Comment: It's the value of `a` (the number of values of `i`) versus `n` that matters to estimating complexity, not the actual values of `i`.

Comment: (In reality this can only execute up to 5 times on any traditional architecture, so a sensible answer is also `O(1)`. Big-O only really matters if there's a reasonable sense in which the scaling term can become dominant over the constant factor.)

Answer (score 0):

To understand the answer you must understand that: Inverse of `Exponent` is not `SQRT`, but `log` is.

This loop is multiplying `i` by itself(.i.e. exponential increment) and will stop only when `i >= n`, therefore the complexity would be `O(log(n))` (log to the base 2 to be precise because `i=2` at initialization)

To illustrate this:
[image: Comparison of SQRT vs Log2]

In the above image, you can see that `SQRT` is giving correct number of steps **only when `i` is a even power of 2**. However `log2` is giving accurate number of steps everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `i` is powered by 2. Hence, if `A(n)` shows the current value of `i` in the last step (which is `n`), it can be written in a recursive for like the following (suppose `n` is power of 2):

```
A(n) = A(n-1)^2
```

Now, you can expand it to find a pattern:

```
A(n) = A(n-2)^4 = A(n-3)^8 = ... = A(n-(n-1))^(2^(n-1)) = 2^(2^(n-1))
```

Hence, the loop iterates `k` step such that `n = 2 ^ (2^ (k-1))`. Therefore, this loop iterates `Theta(log(log(n))`.